# Localbitcoins API Signature in POST request C#

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to send some bitcoin with Localbitcoins API, but it cause Bad request error. when i get balance it works but when try to send bitcoin catch error.

It seems have a problem with signature and parameter (address and amount). beacause when i make a WalletBallance request with wrong Hmac_secret, it gets same error(Error 400 Bad request).

```
 public string SendBitcoin(string address, string amount)
{
    string jsonBody = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
        address = address,
        amount = amount
    });
    return SendRequest("/api/wallet-send/", jsonBody, "POST");
}

public string WalletBalance()
{ 
    return SendRequest("/api/wallet-balance/", "", "GET"); 
}

private string SendRequest(string endpoint, string bodyJson, string Method)
{
    string Hmac_Key = "key";        
    string Hmac_Secret = "secret";
    string timestamp = GetNonce(); 
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urllink + endpoint);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpWebRequest.Method = Method;
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Apiauth-Key", Hmac_Key);
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Apiauth-Nonce", timestamp);        
    if (Method == "POST")
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(bodyJson);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
    }
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Apiauth-Signature", SigneRequest(Hmac_Key, timestamp, Method, endpoint, bodyJson, Hmac_Secret));
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        return result;
    }
}

private string GetNonce()
{
    DateTimeOffset eposh = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0));
    DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    TimeSpan ts = now.Subtract(eposh);
    return ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#0");
}

private string SigneRequest(string HmacKey, string nonce, string method, string endpoint, string body, string HmacSecret)
{
    string message = nonce + HmacKey + endpoint + body; 
    return BitConverter.ToString(HashHMAC(StringEncode(HmacSecret), StringEncode(message))).Replace("-", "").ToUpper();
}

private byte[] StringEncode(string text)
{
    var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(text);
}

private static byte[] HashHMAC(byte[] key, byte[] message)
{
    var hash = new HMACSHA256(key);
    return hash.ComputeHash(message);
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: `StringEncode` can’t be correct. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding but your hash is a byte array of 8-bit bytes, so any byte value which is larger than 127 gets replaced by a question mark. Are you sure you do need to apply a certain character set to convert bytes to a string? Usually when arbitrary bytes should be encoded as a string this is done via Base64 encoding or converting them to a hex string. That aside a) your `GetNonceMethod` can be reduced to `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()`; b) WebRequest is obsolete for almost 10 years now - use HttpClient instead.

Comment: Another issue is that your content type doesn’t match. You state it’s URL-encoded form data, but actually send JSON. So either your content type should be `"application/json"` or you need to send your data as URL-encoded form data.

Comment: Thanks for reply, The problem was parameters. so i replace it with 'string jsonBody = "address=" + address + "&amount=" + amount;' and everyting is fine.

Comment: Yes, that’s the URL-encoded form data format. Though you should use `Uri.EscapeDataString(address)` and `Uri.EscapeDataString(amount)` to handle reserved characters.

Comment: Though like I stated using HttpClient, i.e. `var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary { ["address"] = address, ["amount"] = amount }}); var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`, would make the code much simpler and automatically handle all edge cases.